# selenium xpath doesn't return title for link

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to print a title from a link, but it doesn't return any values. Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Link to HTML for the link I'm trying to get the title from - [http://imgur.com/a/niTAs](https://imgur.com/a/niTAs)

```
driver.get("http://www.theflightdeal.com/category/flight-deals/boston-flight-deals/")

results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="post-entry half_post half_post_odd"]')


for result in results:
    main = result.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="entry-content"]')
    title1 = main.find_element_by_xpath('//h1/a')
    title = title1.get_attribute('title')
    print(title)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prepend a `.` to your xpaths.

An xpath starting with `/` will search in the root of the current document, instead of within the current element. [See function docs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py#L247).

> ```
>     This will select the first link under this element.
>     ::
>         myelement.find_elements_by_xpath(".//a")
>     However, this will select the first link on the page.
>     ::
>         myelement.find_elements_by_xpath("//a")
> ```